# Setting bits on cpp_int

Tags: c++, boost, bit-manipulation, boost-multiprecision

Silly question but, does setting bits on a `cpp_int` from the `boost` library work the same as normal numbers?

For instrance, I tried to set some bits on a number like so:

```
vector<bool> bits; //contains 000000000000011010001100101110110011011001101111
cpp_int M = 0;
int k = 48;
for(bool b : bits) M ^= (-b ^ M) & (1UL << k--);
bits.clear();
bits = toBinary(M); //contains 11001011101100110110011011111
```

The `toBinary(cpp_int&x)` method I have gets bits from the number in the simplest way:

```
  vector<int> toBinary(cpp_int&x) {
    vector<int> bin;

    while (x > 0) {
        bin.push_back(int(x % 2));
        x /= 2;
    }

    reverse(bin.begin(), bin.end());

    return bin;
  }
```

I can understand losing the 14 zeros in the beginning, what I don't understand is why do lose not 14 but 20 whole bits. I am fairly new to the `boost` library, so it's most likely a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `unsigned long` is 32 bit on your system. Thus the first masks generated with `(1UL << k--)` with `k--` being 48 to 32 are not what you expect (it's undefined behaviour).

You can fix this by using a larger type, like `unsigned long long`, like `M ^= (-b ^ M) & (1ULL << k--);`.

If you have more than 64 bits, you can probably use `cpp_int` for more bits, like `M ^= (-b ^ M) & (cpp_int(1ULL) << k--);`, or a more economical solution like:

```cpp
cpp_int mask = 1;
mask <<= bits.size();
for (bool b : bits) {
    M ^= (-b ^ M) & mask;
    // Though that can really be `if (b) M |= mask;`
    mask >>= 1;
}
```

Comment: Almost perfect, however the result is 11010001100101110110011011001101111(0) that pesky 0 in brackets at the end shouldn't really be there.

Comment: It is no big deal ofcourse, I just added M >>= 1; right after the loop and the result was perfect, thank you very much.